# Sort a query by a varchar field(which have numerical values) on numerical basis with Jooq

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, varchar, jooq

How can i sort a varchar field , i have taken ID as varchar and i want to sort it numerically.

We can do this in SQL with using

```
sql query ... order by 0+id desc
```

What i have in Jooq is

```
SimpleSelectFinalStep<ScoreCardRecord> q = factory.selectFrom(ScoreCard.SCORE_CARD)
                    .orderBy(OloScoreCard.SCORE_CARD_ID.descending())
                    .limit(0,1);
```

Comment: I have figured it out...

    SimpleSelectFinalStep<ScoreCardRecord> q = factory.selectFrom(ScoreCard.SCORE_CARD)
      .orderBy(factory.plainSQLField("(0+SCORE_CARD_ID)").descending())
      .limit(0,1);

Sorry for disturbing anyone!

Comment: you can answer your own questions on Stackoverflow. That's not disturbing anyone. Other readers with a similar question might stumble upon yours and find your answer, which is helping too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried casting your `VARCHAR` field into a numeric `DataType`? You could do it like this:

```
factory.selectFrom(ScoreCard.SCORE_CARD)
       .orderBy(OloScoreCard.SCORE_CARD_ID.cast(Integer.class).descending())
       .limit(0, 1);
```

That way you could omit using "plain SQL fields"